# PHP new line and text heading for PDF

Tags: php, forms, fpdf

I am using FPDF option and I am pretty new to both PHP and FPDF as well. My below code is writing the text to a PDF file but its being overlapped. Instead how can make the text to print in each line and also I need a heading before the posted data.

My code is

```
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield2']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield3']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield4']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield5']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield6']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield7']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield8']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield9']);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield10']);
```

Current output: `Test Test Test Test Test`

I need output as

```
First name : Test
Last name : Test
Profession : Test
```

in this manner..

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can add a line break with `$pdf->ln()`

Comment: `$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['textfield2'], 0, 1);` would set the position to the beginning of the next line.